# Sheets script amendment to show whole numbers from workbook not decimals

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've pulled together the following script that successfully extracts a range of data from a Sheets workbook, puts it in a HMTL table, and emails that table to the recipient.

The only problem is that, try as I might, I cannot have the email display rounded numbers; they will show in excess of 15 decimal places. Is there a way to clean this up? I have tried a range of solutions, from numberformatting in Script and changing the cell display format in sheets. Nothing will work!

A screenshot of the output is below.

[image]

```
function SendEmail() {
  // Fetch the ingredients
  var ingredients = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ingredients.getRange("F2:G11").getValues(); 


var TABLEFORMAT = 'cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" dir="ltr" border="1" style="width:100%;table-layout:fixed;font-size:10pt;font-family:arial,sans,sans-serif;border-collapse:collapse;border:1px solid #ccc;font-weight:normal;color:black;background-color:white;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;font-style:normal;'
var htmltable = '<table ' + TABLEFORMAT +' ">';

for (row = 0; row<data.length; row++){

htmltable += '<tr>';

for (col = 0 ;col<data[row].length; col++){
  if (data[row][col] === "" || 0) {htmltable += '<td>' + 'None' + '</td>';} 
  else
    if (row === 0)  {
      htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';
    }

  else {htmltable += '<td>' + data[row][col] + '</td>';}
}

     htmltable += '</tr>';
}

     htmltable += '</table>';
     Logger.log(data);
     Logger.log(htmltable);

  // Fetch the email address
      var email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("E21");
      var emailAddress = email.getValues();

  // Fetch the date
  var date = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet2").getRange("E24").getValues();

    // Send Email

  var message = {htmlBody: htmltable};
    var subject = 'Ingredients - '+ date;
  MailApp.sendEmail(emailAddress, subject, '', {htmlBody : htmltable});
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way may be to use

`.getDisplayValues()` instead of `.getValues()`.

So:

```
var data = ingredients.getRange("F2:G11").getDisplayValues();
```

This way you can format the data on the sheet as you like.

And the script will use the numbers as they *appear* on the sheet and not what their *real* values may be.

===========================

Your other options are to use `Math.round()`, `Math.ceil()` or `Math.floor()` functions in the loop when processing `data[row][col]`.

Comment: Thanks ADW! That sorted it immediately. Happy New Year!